# Facing issues in puppetserver - puppet-agent configuration

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, puppet, devops, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

I am trying to set up Puppet for DevOps. I have puppet server in Ubuntu 14.04 and puppet-agent in Windows 10. When I am generating certificate for the first time from puppet-agent (Windows 10) the SSL certficate is generating without any issues and even I can sign the same certificate from puppetserver (Ubuntu 14.04), however after signing when I am trying to update the status in puppet-agent (Windows 10) by "**puppet agent -t**" getting error as,

Error: Could not request certificate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=username-virtualbox.domain.com]

[image]

The puppet configuration file details:

[image]

**puppet.config (puppetserver [Ubuntu]):**

[image]

Troubleshooting steps already tried,

1. Time zone in both the environments are in sync
2. Deleted "ssl" folders containing the details of the ssl certificates from both the environments several times and re-tried
3. 8140 ports are enabled on both Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,

Try to run cmd as admin

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue -- been working it for a few weeks now. I cannot guarantee yet that mine is working correctly all the time. Here are some steps I have taken. I hope they are helpful to others.
I am running Puppet Enterprise 2018.1.4. Puppet Agent 5.5.6 on RHEL 7.4.
1) The SSL routine uses a time stamp. Ensure the time is the same between Master & Client.
2) clean/remove the agent cert from the Master AND the Client. On my RHEL, the Client cert is is in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/* -- remove any files with the agent name in here.
3) Make sure your puppet enabled on your agent: puppet agent --enable
4) If a client does not contact the puppet master "for a while" the master will drop the client from it's node list, but NOT remove the cert. In theory, the master SHOULD return the node to an active status.
5) Can you run the puppet agent on the master & get the expected results? If not -> problem with puppet code, otherwise, problem with agent.
6) Is puppet.conf configured correctly?
 Under the [main] section, do you have the server entry correct? 
Under [agent] are you set to the correct environment? Is noop set to true?
7) It is possible that you have an error in a puppet module that is causeing the agent to exit quietly. Run puppet parser validate on all of your .pp files
8) Can the master resolve the IP address of the master and the client? 
Can the client resolve the the IP address of the master and the client? 
Is resolv.conf set correctly on both hosts?
9) hostnames of the client & master should be correct. Each server should know it's shortname, FQDN and IP. On RHEL, I run: hostname; hostname -f; and hostname -i, respectively.
10) File permissions on all the directories & modules should be correct. Check out a working module, see it's owner, group & permissions. Ensure your module is the same.
11) Only root/admin can correctly run puppet agent.
12) On RHEL, the logs are under /var/log/puppet. Do you see any errors there?
13) run puppet agent with the --debug or the --trace option in addition to -t. Pipe this output to a file and see if you can spot any errors.
14) Can you force the master to run the puppet agent on the client successfully?
Many of these things have been narrowing down my issue. I don't know yet if it is fixed, as It takes a while for a node to drop out. Hopefully these will fix your issue.

Hope it helps. There are LOTS of things that could be going wrong.

Comment: Please inline your answer here

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Don't (only) link to another answer. Post a full response here